# how to verify the archive code submitted to the app store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I submitted my Full and Lite version of my iOS App to the Apple App Store for an incremental release (1.2) - both Apps are already For Sale.  I added In-App purchases to my Lite version.

My Full version was approved, but my Lite version was not.  In discussing with Apple, they have provided a screen shot showing that they can't access the In-App functionality in the Lite version, but the screenshot is from my Full version, which doesn't have that functionality.

I'm appealing, and am hopeful that they will address.

This is the first time any App I've had was rejected, and I have several questions that I would appreciate any suggestions from developers who have gone through this.

1. Is there a way for me to run the exact code that I submitted from the Organizer/Archive so that I can verify that my Lite version is indeed the Lite version and not the Full version?  I can see them in on the local file system, and there are 2 different, distinct files that have different sizes.
2. If I have to rebuild my App and resubmit can I do that from the same archive that is in Organizer?
3. If I have to rebuild, I think I'm in a bit of trouble, because I've been heads down on the next release for the past week and a half.  Is there a way to access the version that was used to build the archive?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can resign the released version to be an adhoc version and run it on your device.
2. If it requires a new build it won't let you submit with the same version number which will probably stop you from using the same archive unfortunately.
3. It has been my practice to make a snapshot for every release for this case. If you don't have a saved snapshot or if you aren't using source control then you may be out of luck on that one.

Comment: Yeah - I didn't realize the archive and snapshot weren't one and the same - on point #3, I guess that is what I'll do going forward too.

Comment: For comment #1 - what is involved in resigning the released version to be ad-hoc?

Comment: When you go to the organizer->archives you can select your archive that you submitted (this theory falls apart if you deleted it). Then click "Distribute" and select save for enterprise and ad hoc distribution. You will need a valid ad hoc provisioning profile that is associated with your bundle ID and is set up with your testing devices and you should be able to install and run it on physical devices.